# Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, rename (even though the directory exists)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, express, path

I am just learning express.js for a while.I am just learning image upload using angular.js,When the file uploaded to temp dir,I have to move that file to a new directory.Yes, That directory exists.But it still shows this error.

```
User 572b94b4f30179941f5f7c5dis submittin { fieldName: 'file',
  originalFilename: 'Capture.PNG',
  path: 'C:\\Users\\arfo\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\zK2-mOXhXflzjrKfxoACnuiw.PNG',
  headers:
   { 'content-disposition': 'form-data; name="file"; filename="Capture.PNG"',
     'content-type': 'image/png' },
  size: 92643,
  name: 'Capture.PNG',
  type: 'image/png' }
{ [Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, rename 'C:\Users\arfo\AppData\Local\Temp\zK2-mOXhXflzjrKfxoACnuiw.PNG' -> 'C:\Users\arfo\Desktop\all folders\sn\uploads\572b94b4f30179941f5f
7c5d2016-05-06T12:15:52.934ZCapture.PNG']
  errno: -4058,
  code: 'ENOENT',
  syscall: 'rename',
```

But i have that directory exists

```
C:\Users\arfo\Desktop\all folders\sn\uploads
```

This is my code
profile-controller.js

```
var User = require('../datasets/users');
var fs = require('fs-extra');
var path = require('path');

module.exports.updatePhoto = function (req,res) {
    var file = req.files.file;
    var userId = req.body.userId;
    console.log("User " + userId+"is submittin" , file);    
    var uploadDate = new Date().toISOString();   

    var tempPath = file.path;
    var targetPath = path.join(__dirname, "../../uploads/"+ userId + uploadDate +file.name);
    var savepath = "/uploads/"+userId+ uploadDate +file.name;

    fs.rename(tempPath,targetPath,function (err) {
        if(err){
            console.log(err)
        }else{
            console.log("filemoved");
            /*User.findById(userId,function (err,userData) {
                var user = userData;
                  user.image = savepath;
                  user.save(function (err) {
                      if (err){
                          console.log("Faile ");
                      }else{
                          console.log("Save success");
                      }
                  })
            })*/
        }

    })
};
```

Comment: Try it without the uploadDate. It might not like the `:`

Comment: Ya its working but what should i do if i want uploader current timestamp @Molda

Comment: You could simply replace `:` with `-` like this `uploadDate = uploadDate.replace(':', '-');`